# Align x86-64 and AArch64 callsites

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, x86-64, memory-alignment, arm64

I would like your insight.
Say I have a function `main` that calls `foo`. Assume that I have compiled the same code for `x86-64` and `AArch64`. And that the function symbols lie at the same (virtual) address in both binaries.
For example, for `x86-64`:

```
0000000000501060 <main>:
  501060:    55                     push   rbp
  501061:    48 89 e5               mov    rbp,rsp
  501064:    48 83 ec 10            sub    rsp,0x10
  ...
  50108f:    e8 9c ff ff ff         call   501030 <foo>
  ...
```

and for `AArch64`:

```
0000000000501060 <main>:
  501060:    d10083ff     sub    sp, sp, #0x20
  501064:    a9017bfd     stp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
   ...
  50108c:    97ffffe9     bl     501030 <foo>
  ...
```

I want to somehow also align the callsites, i.e., `50108f` and `50108c`, so that the return addresses, after `foo` returns, will be the same.

I am trying to modify the LLVM backend for both targets, and thinking that maybe I could overwrite one `MCInst` method that generated the callsite, and add some padding (with nop) before one of the two callsites, in order to align them.

But, I am not sure if this is the way to go, and was looking for ideas. Also, I understand that there is the `MCCodePadder` that may handle my instruction's padding, but still I am not sure how could one backend (`x86-64`) get the information for the location of the address emitted by the other backend (`AArch64`).

Comment: Note that the return address is the instruction *after* the call / bl, i.e. `0x...94` (x86-64) or `0x...90` (arm64).  So yes, with on ARM64 NOP, you'd be aligned, but I have no idea how to convince LLVM to make a specific callsite produce a return address with some fixed offset from function entry, in the face of possible code changes or different optimization levels.  If you don't care about robustness, can you just `asm("nop");` in the ARM64 source?

Comment: I think you could hack something up with `__asm__ volatile(".p2align [...]")`, but there's no way it would be stable... unless you also put the branching instructions in there and used extended asm along with `register __asm__ ("x0")` etc to manually assign arguments to registers according to the ABI.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't want to modify the source of the code. I would like the compiler to insert the padding for me. Thanks for your comment. I was relying on that LLVM can query information on the code to be emitted, right before code emission, after all optimizations. But, I wasn't sure how to exchange this information between the architectures.

Comment: @Siguza I don't want to modify the source every time, but have the compiler to insert the padding for me. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: How "general" does this have to be?  If you don't know ahead of time whether the AArch64 or x86-64 version would have a later return address, you might have to compile a 3rd time (after collecting information from the first 2 runs).  Or else pessimistically always pad the call site some in the first one to be compiled.  (If that's the x86-64 version, of course it should make sure the call instruction ends at a 4-byte boundary, i.e. starts at `addr%4 = 3` for a normal call, or `addr % 4 = 2` for a `-fno-plt` 6-byte call through the GOT.) No idea how much work it would be to get LLVM to do that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will give the 3rd compilation a shot if need be! I will, also, keep in mind the alignment constraints, you are right.